# Grails: cannot populate <g:select> (Newbie: Possibly whole approach is wrong)

Tags: jquery, grails

I know I must be doing something very simple but wrong. I have a page which has a hidden div in it. jQuery makes that div show up when you click a button on the page. When the div shows, it has a formRemote which contains a drop down list I need to populate but I can only get an empty drop down list to appear.

Here is the g:select list in the formRemote as described:

```
<g:formRemote name="editinstitutionForm" url="[controller:'admin', action:'editInstitution']" onSuccess="doResult2(data)">
                <label>Institution: </label><g:select name = "pickInst" from = "${instlist}" style = "border-radius: 5px"></g:select><br><br>
                <label>New name: </label><g:textField name="username" style = "border-radius: 5px"></g:textField><br><br>

                <div id = "submit3"><g:submitButton id = "submit_button3" name="Submit"/></div>
            </g:formRemote>
```

Here is the button code that makes the div containing the g:select appear(using jQuery):

```
<button class = "adminoption" id = "editInst" onclick = "${remoteFunction(action:'updateInstlist', controller: 'admin')}">Edit An Institution</button>
```

when this button is clicked I am also calling a function in the controller to ready the list to be shown, here is that function:

```
def updateInstlist = { 
    instlist = Institution.list().collect {it.username}.sort(java.text.Collator.instance)
    return [instlist: instlist]
}
```

I know the list above is not null and ready to go because I have tried printing it to the console. I'm sure it is something simple just don't know what I'm doing wrong. Im not sure that the jQuery code the button invokes will help but I"ll include it:

```
$("#editInst").click( function() {
            $("#institutionEntered").hide();
            $("#pleaseChoose").hide();
            $("#institutionInfo2").hide();
            $("#editedInstitution").hide();
            $("#leftEntryForm").show();
            $("#instInfo3").show();
            $("#editInstInfo").show();
        });
```

Finally, when I do click the button that shows the div with the g:select, here is what I get in the Chrome debug console:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/FatcaOne_0/admin/updateInstlist 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
send jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
onclick
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `optionKey` and `optionValue` attributes to `g:select`?

Comment: @Donal, since by default toString() is called on each element of the "from" list, Im not sure what I would set optionKey or optionValue to. Therefore, I did not try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can see you populate the g:select each time you press the button and each time retrieving data from database if i am right that is not good, here is my recommendation, in order to populate g:select implement your code Institution.list().... int the action that generate described view and pass it as a model and fill your g.select tag right from the beginning and it will be filled when user display the div

i hope it can be helpful

Comment: Thank you so much. I had thought about this approach but do not know why I didn't try it. Maybe I did but didn't do it correctly. I just did it now and it works a wonder.